# startx /bin/bash in fullscreen without desktop

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

Ok so I know it's a weird case but hang in here with me.

So the thing is I've got an very old laptop running ubuntu 14.04 server without any desktop aka shell only. BUT the laptop also has a touch screen so we want to be able to use the "mouse"/touchscreen/touchpad to select text inside the terminal and/or click/copy/paste/cut/etc. It's part of art project with some students and also one of the tasks is to run as less as possible. So running a desktop in the background is not really an option. My question is:

Is there a way to start the Ubuntu terminal as UI application in fullscreen without the actual desktop in the background but giving the functionality of an mouse cursor.

(If someone knows a even better solution for adding a mouse without starting the desktop its appreciated)

Comment: There are lots of good tiling window managers available -- which will, by default, start *whatever* they start purely full-screen. That said, I'm by no means convinced that this is a question about software development, and thus that it is in any way, shape or form topical here on StackOverflow. Consider [ubuntu.se], insofar as you're interested in tools for that specific distro.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: create a `~/.xinitrc` with content : `exec gnome-terminal`, then run `startx`

Or another solution is to stay in [tty](/questions/tagged/tty) and install `gpm` for mouse control

Comment: helped a lot thanks

Comment: Be careful answering questions like these. Some in the community feel answers should be downvoted, too. Also see [Should one downvote answers to off-topic questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194963/173448)

Comment: From your link: _Please remember the bit of the downvote tooltip of "this is not useful" is still the guiding principle for what to downvote... but if it isn't useful, by all means, downvote it._